# need a regular expression to search a matching last name

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a javascript array which holds strings of last names.
I need to loop this array and separate out the last names which match a given string.

```
var names = ['woods','smith','smike'];
var test = 'smi';
var c = 0;
var result = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
{
if(names[i].match(test))// need regular expression for this
result[c++] = names[i];
}
return result;
```

name should match the test string even if the test lies within the name. so... mik should match 'Mike' and 'Smike' also.

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript string .search is what you're looking for.. You don't even need regex although search supports that too.

```
var names = ['woods','smith','smike'];
var test = 'smi';
var c = 0;
var result = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
{
if(names[i].toLowerCase().search(test))// need regular expression for this
result.push(names[i]);
}
return result;
```

Comment: You'd probably want to use `names[i].toLowerCase()`, because `search` is case sensitive. Also, if I remember correctly, you should check it against `-1`.

Comment: hmm... did not know about search in js. Glad I know this now. Thanks guys! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a regex from a string:

```
var nameRe = new RegExp("mik", "i");
if(names[i].match(nameRe))
{
    result.push(names[i]);
}
```

Make sure to escape regex meta-characters though - if your string may contain them. For example `^`, `$` may result in a miss-match, and `*`, `?` `)` and more may result in an invalid regex.

More info: [regular-expressions.info/javascript](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without regex:

```
if (names[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(test.toLowerCase()) >= 0)
    // ...
```

Comment: Thats correct... I should have thought about this too. Simple and easy. Thank you aaz!

Comment: @zoom - you should accept this answer, in my opinion, it is the best one. Note that on the `search` option you also need to check for `>= 0` - the posted code is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with one regex.

```
var r = new RegExp(names.join('|'), "igm");

'woods smith'.match(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for this, so I'd recommend using string manipulation instead. It's almost (*almost!*) always better to use string functions instead of regex when you can: They're usually faster, and it's harder to make a mistake.

```
for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
{
    if(names[i].indexOf(test) > -1)
        //match, do something with names[i]...
}
```